# Artemis-2.6.3 console: Service Unavailable

Tags: java, activemq-artemis

I started artemis-service successfully. But web console not working.

cmnd: **sudo "/usr/lib/myBroker/bin/artemis-service" start**

url: *http://ip:8161/console/*

response:

> HTTP ERROR 503 Problem accessing /console/. Reason:
>
> ```
> Service Unavailable
> ```

I change the **bootstrap.xml** to access **8161** port from outside.

From: **bind="http://localhost:8161"**

To: **bind="http://0.0.0.0:8161"**

**N.B**: when I start it in my local-machine working fine without change bootstrap.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

This problem occurred for jolokia-access.xml.
remove allow-origin and add below configuration:

```
<remote>
      <host>localhost</host>
      <host>192.168.0.0/16</host>
</remote>
```

Here I allowed 192.168 block ip.

Documentation [here](https://jolokia.org/reference/html/security.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem when i tried to setup the broker as Windows service.
After some tries i just start the broker by executing:

**artemis run**

(from broker bin directory)
Now i got access to the console.

Answer (score -2):

```
 26         <!-- Allow cross origin access from localhost ... -->
 27         <allow-origin>*</allow-origin>
```

match all

Comment: Hi, code-only answers are not useful in the long run. Please, add some details and/or explain it.