# Cant access Artemis console

Tags: activemq-artemis, jolokia

I have just install a new artemis in my new server, able to run the service normally but not able to access from outside.

I also have followed this question that seems have the similar issue with me, but 
seems not able to work.

[Artemis-2.6.3 console: Service Unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53257375/artemis-2-6-3-console-service-unavailable)

my current jolokia-access :

```
<restrict>
    <remote>
      <host>localhost</host>
      <host>10.85.102.148</host><!--This is my computer ip-->
    </remote>   
    <!--
    <cors>
        <allow-origin>*://localhost*</allow-origin>
        <strict-checking/>
    </cors>
    -->
</restrict>
```

current logging

```
    2019-04-25 20:16:07,013 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.integration.bootstrap] AMQ101000: Starting ActiveMQ Artemis Server
2019-04-25 20:16:07,046 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221000: live Message Broker is starting with configuration Broker Configuration (clustered=false,journalDirectory=data/journal,bindingsDirectory=data/bindings,largeMessagesDirectory=data/large-messages,pagingDirectory=data/paging)
2019-04-25 20:16:07,080 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221012: Using AIO Journal
2019-04-25 20:16:07,133 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221057: Global Max Size is being adjusted to 1/2 of the JVM max size (-Xmx). being defined as 1,073,741,824
2019-04-25 20:16:07,162 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-server]. Adding protocol support for: CORE
2019-04-25 20:16:07,163 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-amqp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: AMQP
2019-04-25 20:16:07,164 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-hornetq-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: HORNETQ
2019-04-25 20:16:07,164 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-mqtt-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: MQTT
2019-04-25 20:16:07,165 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-openwire-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: OPENWIRE
2019-04-25 20:16:07,166 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-stomp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: STOMP
2019-04-25 20:16:07,222 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221034: Waiting indefinitely to obtain live lock
2019-04-25 20:16:07,223 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221035: Live Server Obtained live lock
2019-04-25 20:16:08,143 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address DLQ supporting [ANYCAST]
2019-04-25 20:16:08,144 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue DLQ on address DLQ
2019-04-25 20:16:08,144 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address ExpiryQueue supporting [ANYCAST]
2019-04-25 20:16:08,144 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue ExpiryQueue on address ExpiryQueue
2019-04-25 20:16:08,513 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 0.0.0.0:61619 for protocols [CORE,MQTT,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,OPENWIRE]
2019-04-25 20:16:08,521 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 0.0.0.0:5446 for protocols [HORNETQ,STOMP]
2019-04-25 20:16:08,536 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 0.0.0.0:5673 for protocols [AMQP]
2019-04-25 20:16:08,540 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 0.0.0.0:1884 for protocols [MQTT]
2019-04-25 20:16:08,545 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 0.0.0.0:61614 for protocols [STOMP]
2019-04-25 20:16:08,547 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221007: Server is now live
2019-04-25 20:16:08,548 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221001: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 2.6.4 [0.0.0.0, nodeID=c4f07cfd-6745-11e9-bfbc-005056b0ef9d]
2019-04-25 20:16:09,647 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.branding.PluginContextListener] Initialized activemq-branding plugin
2019-04-25 20:16:09,749 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.plugin.PluginContextListener] Initialized artemis-plugin plugin
2019-04-25 20:16:10,199 INFO  [io.hawt.HawtioContextListener] Initialising hawtio services
2019-04-25 20:16:10,269 INFO  [io.hawt.system.ConfigManager] Configuration will be discovered via system properties
2019-04-25 20:16:10,273 INFO  [io.hawt.jmx.JmxTreeWatcher] Welcome to hawtio 1.5.5 : http://hawt.io/ : Don't cha wish your console was hawt like me? ;-)
2019-04-25 20:16:10,298 INFO  [io.hawt.jmx.UploadManager] Using file upload directory: /opt/CMS/dev/artemisCMSDEV2.6.4/tmp/uploads
2019-04-25 20:16:10,318 INFO  [io.hawt.web.AuthenticationFilter] Starting hawtio authentication filter, JAAS realm: "activemq" authorized role(s): "amq" role principal classes: "org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.RolePrincipal"
2019-04-25 20:16:10,362 INFO  [io.hawt.web.JolokiaConfiguredAgentServlet] Jolokia overridden property: [key=policyLocation, value=file:/opt/CMS/dev/artemisCMSDEV2.6.4/etc/jolokia-access.xml]
2019-04-25 20:16:10,403 INFO  [io.hawt.web.RBACMBeanInvoker] Using MBean [hawtio:type=security,area=jmx,rank=0,name=HawtioDummyJMXSecurity] for role based access control
2019-04-25 20:16:10,581 INFO  [io.hawt.system.ProxyWhitelist] Initial proxy whitelist: [localhost, 127.0.0.1, 10.92.202.52, mask.myserver.com, 192.168.46.52, mask-p1.myserver.com]
2019-04-25 20:16:10,882 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241001: HTTP Server started at http://localhost:8162
2019-04-25 20:16:10,883 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241002: Artemis Jolokia REST API available at http://localhost:8162/console/jolokia
2019-04-25 20:16:10,883 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241004: Artemis Console available at http://localhost:8162/console
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the log the console is bound to `http://localhost:8162` therefore not accessible from outside `localhost`. Please check the `bind` entry in `bootstrap.xml`.
Also note that you have a restriction with `localhost` in `cors` section of `jolokia-access.xml` what you also should adjust.

Answer (score 6):

You need just to modify these two files us below :

$[broker_artemis_path]/etc/bootstrap.xml

```
<web bind="http://0.0.0.0:8161" path="web">
       <app url="activemq-branding" war="activemq-branding.war"/>
       <app url="artemis-plugin" war="artemis-plugin.war"/>
       <app url="console" war="console.war"/>
</web>
```

and  $[broker_artemis_path]/etc/jolokia-access.xml

```
<cors>
            <!-- Allow cross origin access from localhost ... -->
            <allow-origin>*://*</allow-origin>
            <!-- Options from this point on are auto-generated by Create.java from the Artemis CLI -->
            <!-- Check for the proper origin on the server side, too -->
            <strict-checking/>
</cors>
```

For more information you can check this link :
https://medium.com/@hasnat.saeed/setup-activemq-artemis-on-ubuntu-18-04-76bb4975308b